# basemap: How to remove actual lat/lon lines while keeping the ticks on the axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plotted a map by basemap as below:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7,6))
m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=40.125,urcrnrlat=44.625,\
        llcrnrlon=-71.875,urcrnrlon=-66.375,resolution='h')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(int(40.125),int(44.625),1),labels=[1,0,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(int(-71.875),int(-66.375),1),labels=[0,0,0,1])
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='grey')
m.drawmapboundary()
```

The picture as below:
[image]

How can I remove actual lat/lon lines while keeping the ticks on the axis?

Comment: I don't quite understand, are you wanting to remove the actual latitude longitudinal lines while keeping the ticks on the axis? As far as I understand parallels/meridians and lat/lon are the same thing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by setting the `linewidth` parameter to zero

```
m.drawparallels(np.arange(int(40.125),int(44.625),1),labels=[1,0,0,0], linewidth=0.0)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(int(-71.875),int(-66.375),1),labels=[0,0,0,1], linewidth=0.0)
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect `linestyle='none'` would also work and is a bit more semantically correct (doesn't draw lines instead of drawing zero-width lines).

Comment: @tcaswell nice idea but I'm afraid `drawmeridians()` raises `AttributeError: Unknown property linestyle`.

Comment: huh, ok.  I incorrectly assumed that extra `kwargs` are passed to the underlying `plot`, but they are passed to the call to `text`.  I apologize. [looks like they do linestyle control through `dashes`]

Comment: This removes the lines, but not "keeping the ticks".

Answer (score 4):

I found the basemap ticks setting quite confusing.

The figure below shows 8 different setups. Some notations:

- `ST=T`: `suppress_ticks=True`.
- `ST=F`: `suppress_ticks=False`.
- `DP-DR`: `drawparallels()` and `drawmeridians()`.
- `DP-DR(LW=0)`: `drawparallels(...,linewidth=0)` and `drawmeridians(...,linewidth=0)`.
- `mill`: miller map projection.

[image]

Interpret the results in the top panel:

- (a): This is the same as the OP's figure, i.e. using `suppress_ticks=True` (the default) and `drawparallels()` and `drawmeridians()`.
- (b): Solution suggested by @Greg, setting `linewidth=0` to `drawparallels()` and `drawmeridians()` removes the grid lines, but not adding the ticks. Note the title of the question is "How to remove actual lat/lon lines while keeping the ticks on the axis".
- (c): Solution suggested by @Janusz. Note that setting `suppress_ticks=False` alone does not remove the grid lines, instead it adds an extra set of ticks. That's why `suppress_ticks` is default to `True`.
- (d): Combine (b) and (c). `linewidth=0` is what actually removes the grid lines. Again `suppress_ticks=False` introduces extra ticks, and they overlap with ticks added by `drawparallels()` and `drawmeridians()`.

2nd panel:

- (e): What if we don't use `drawparallels()` and `drawmeridians()` and let it automatically add ticks? The 1st drawback is that you don't get to control which ticks to add. Another one is the tick labels are formatted without the `W/E`, `N/S` symbols (if you add `labelstyle='+/-'` to `drawparallels()` or `drawmeridians()`, the labels will use `+ 41^{\circ}` format). And there is another big drawback, as shown in (f).
- (f): This is using `mill` map projection instead of `cyl`. Notice the automatic labeling uses meter as unit rather than degree of latitude/longitude. Not good (at least in this case).
- (g): This is trying to add the tickmarks by manually setting ticks, by `ax.set_xticks(lon_ticks)` and `ax.set_yticks(lat_ticks)`. The ticks are added, but labels overlap.
- (h): This is my proposed solution again using `mill` projection:

```
m = Basemap(projection='mill',llcrnrlat=40.125,urcrnrlat=44.625,\
        llcrnrlon=-71.875,urcrnrlon=-66.375,resolution='l',
        ax=ax8, fix_aspect=False,
        suppress_ticks=True)

m.drawcoastlines()

lat_ticks=np.arange(np.ceil(40.125),int(44.625),1)
lon_ticks=np.arange(np.ceil(-71.875),int(-66.375),1)

# convert from degree to map projection
lon_ticks_proj, _=m(lon_ticks, np.zeros(len(lon_ticks)))
_, lat_ticks_proj=m(np.zeros(len(lat_ticks)), lat_ticks)
# manually add ticks
ax8.set_xticks(lon_ticks_proj)
ax8.set_yticks(lat_ticks_proj)
ax8.tick_params(axis='both',which='major')
# add ticks to the opposite side as well
ax8.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
ax8.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
# remove the tick labels
ax8.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax8.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])

m.drawparallels(lat_ticks,labels=[1,0,0,0],linewidth=0,
        xoffset=0.03*abs(m.xmax-m.xmin)) # need to enlarge the offset a bit
m.drawmeridians(lon_ticks,labels=[0,0,0,1],linewidth=0,
        yoffset=0.03*abs(m.ymax-m.ymin)) # need to enlarge the offset a bit
```

Finally, the script to create the figure:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

def getBM(ax, suppress_ticks, projection='cyl'):
    m = Basemap(projection=projection,llcrnrlat=40.125,urcrnrlat=44.625,\
            llcrnrlon=-71.875,urcrnrlon=-66.375,resolution='l',
            ax=ax, fix_aspect=False,
            suppress_ticks=suppress_ticks)

    m.drawcoastlines()

    return m

lat_ticks=np.arange(np.ceil(40.125),int(44.625),1)
lon_ticks=np.arange(np.ceil(-71.875),int(-66.375),1)

figure=plt.figure(figsize=(14,7),dpi=100)
nrows=2; ncols=4

#------------------------s1------------------------
ax1=figure.add_subplot(nrows,ncols,1)
m = getBM(ax1, True)

m.drawparallels(lat_ticks,labels=[1,0,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(lon_ticks,labels=[0,0,0,1])
ax1.set_title('(a) ST=T, DP-DR')

#------------------------s2------------------------
ax2=figure.add_subplot(nrows,ncols,2)
m = getBM(ax2, True)

m.drawparallels(lat_ticks,labels=[1,0,0,0],linewidth=0)
m.drawmeridians(lon_ticks,labels=[0,0,0,1],linewidth=0)
ax2.set_title('(b) ST=T, DP-DR(LW=0)')

#------------------------s3------------------------
ax3=figure.add_subplot(nrows,ncols,3)
m = getBM(ax3, False)

m.drawparallels(lat_ticks,labels=[1,0,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(lon_ticks,labels=[0,0,0,1])
ax3.set_title('(c) ST=F, DP-DR')

#------------------------s4------------------------
ax4=figure.add_subplot(nrows,ncols,4)
m = getBM(ax4, False)

m.drawparallels(lat_ticks,labels=[1,0,0,0],linewidth=0)
m.drawmeridians(lon_ticks,labels=[0,0,0,1],linewidth=0)
ax4.set_title('(d) ST=F, DP-DR(LW=0)')

#------------------------s5------------------------
ax5=figure.add_subplot(nrows,ncols,5)
m = getBM(ax5, False)

ax5.set_title('(e) ST=F')

#------------------------s6------------------------
ax6=figure.add_subplot(nrows,ncols,6)
m = getBM(ax6, False, projection='mill')

ax6.set_title('(f) ST=F, mill')

#------------------------s7------------------------
ax7=figure.add_subplot(nrows,ncols,7)
m = getBM(ax7, True)

ax7.set_xticks(lon_ticks)
ax7.set_yticks(lat_ticks)
m.drawparallels(lat_ticks,labels=[1,0,0,0],linewidth=0)
m.drawmeridians(lon_ticks,labels=[0,0,0,1],linewidth=0)
ax7.set_title('(g) ST=T, DP-DR(LW=0), manual tick')

#------------------------s8------------------------
ax8=figure.add_subplot(nrows,ncols,8)
m = getBM(ax8, True, projection='mill')

# convert from degree to map projection
lon_ticks_proj, _=m(lon_ticks, np.zeros(len(lon_ticks)))
_, lat_ticks_proj=m(np.zeros(len(lat_ticks)), lat_ticks)
# manually add ticks
ax8.set_xticks(lon_ticks_proj)
ax8.set_yticks(lat_ticks_proj)
ax8.tick_params(axis='both',which='major')
# add ticks to the opposite side as well
ax8.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
ax8.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
# remove the tick labels
ax8.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax8.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])

m.drawparallels(lat_ticks,labels=[1,0,0,0],linewidth=0,
        xoffset=0.03*abs(m.xmax-m.xmin)) # need to enlarge the offset a bit
m.drawmeridians(lon_ticks,labels=[0,0,0,1],linewidth=0,
        yoffset=0.03*abs(m.ymax-m.ymin)) # need to enlarge the offset a bit
ax8.set_title('(g) ST=T, DP-DR(LW=0), manual tick*')

figure.tight_layout()
figure.show()
```

**UPDATE**: I'm having some issues with saved PDF files when using `drawparallels(..., linewidth=0)` and `drawmeridians(..., linewidth=0)`. More details are given at https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/493.

If you have the similar issue, consider using `drawparallels(..., zorder=-2)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

In `basemap` you can set `suppress_ticks=False` and you get the ticks without the lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the gridlines while keeping the labels and tickmarks by using `dashes=[dash_length,dash_spacing]` option which is actually for setting the dash length and spacing. Set the spacing value to a value larger than your figure size like below.

```
m.drawparallels(np.arange(0,50,5),labels=[1,0,0,0],linewidth=0.9,dashes=[4,9900])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(50,100,5),labels=[0,0,0,1],linewidth=0.9,dashes=[4,9900])
```

[Example figure with ticks and labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o65cp.png)