# Tickmarks on basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

To draw meridian lines on a python basemap is a fairly simple job:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
map = Basemap(epsg=3395,
projection="merc",
resolution = 'h', area_thresh = 0.01,
llcrnrlon=0, llcrnrlat=60,
urcrnrlon=5, urcrnrlat=70, ax=ax)

meridians = np.arange(0,5,1)
map.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[1,0,0,1])
```

However, I rather want tickmarks alongside the axis, instead of the dotted lines over my map, as I feel it obstructs the map content.

I tried with the following, to no avail:

```
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,5,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I drew parallels, but assured that they only was drawn at the bottom:

```
    np.linspace(startlat,endlat,5) # 5 = number of "ticks"
    map.drawmeridians(meridianinterval,labels=[0,0,0,1], dashes=[6,900], color='w')
```

See the dashes option, which draws 6 pixel long dashes 900 pixels apart (only on the bottom).

Comment: `ax.xaxis.set_ticks()` works, but you need to give it the correct values, and remove the tick labels otherwise they will overlap with those added by `drawmeridians()`. You may want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62087643/2005415).